# Conformally flat coordinate system on a surface

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth map and Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the graph of $f$. We know that every surface is conformally flat where the metric is given from the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$. I would like to know the coordinate system $(x,y)$ on S such that its metric is of the form $g=e^{\lambda(x,y)} ((dx)^2+(dy)^2)$ for some function $\lambda$.

Comment: What do you mean by "know"? This coordinate system is obtained by solving some nonlinear PDE (say, the Beltrami equation). There is no "formula" for these solutions.

Comment: @MoisheCohen    I mean by "know" just the existence of such coordinate system such that the metric becomes a conformally flat metric. So by your comment I know that such coordinate system can be found for a given $f$.